# Wifi direct with multiple connection in Android

Tags: android, connection, android-wifi, adhoc, wifi-direct

As I know wifi direct in Android can support two mode that is 1 to 1 and 1 to many. 
I'm trying to implement an APP to simulate multiple P2P connection through wifi direct. But I'm not sure does wifi direct in Android support concurrent connection(many to many)? When A---B---C already connected via wifi direct which B is the group owner, can I have another device D to make connection with C? Or is there other way can simulate multiple device P2P connection? Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

if A,B,C are in a group with B acting as group owner and if another device D wants to connect to C ,
First of all C wont be visible to D  as a peer once it is the part of a group. Only the device acting as Group owner will be visible to the new device (all other members of group will be hidden). Even if you send a request from C to D the request of D shall be forwarded to the Group owner (i.e it will essentially try to become part of the preexisting group)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I want to know is there any other method can reach concurrent connection between multiple nodes in Android? Or they can communicate with each other without connection just like wifi beacon frame? I want to implement a network topology like Wireless Sensor Network in Android, but I don't know how to communicate between each node.